# In class initialization and initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, in-class-initialization

I have recently discovered that you cant have at the same time in class initialization and initializer list.
The following code fails :

```
struct s
{
    int i=0;    
};
int main() {
    s s1; //s1.i = 0
    //s s2={42}; //fails
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the in class initialization, the initializer list works fine !

Can someone explains me why a such thing is no allowed ?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling in C++11 mode? Does the compiler really have it implemented? Which compiler and what version of it do you have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact this is allowed in C++14.

```
struct s
{
    int i=0;    
};

int main() {
    s s1;
    s s2 = {42}; // succeeds
}
```

It's likely that your compiler just isn't implementing the new rule in C++14. The latest version of clang, however, accepts this and does the correct thing in C++14 mode.

When in-class initialization was added to C++11 it was specified such that it prevented a class from being an aggregate. This was done because at the time the aggregate concept was closely related to PoD types which need to be trivially constructible. Having an in-class initialization means that a type is no longer trivially constructible. Since then, however, the two concepts have become more independent, and so for C++14 a short proposal reversing that decision was accepted.

Comment: It doesn't with GCC 4.8.

Comment: I don't think it is legal in C++11. See my answer.

Comment: @thokra I had thought it was in gcc 4.9, but it isn't there either.

Comment: @bames53: Ah, C++14 ... now we're talking. ;)

Comment: Oki, thanks for the answer. I'm using g++ 4.8.1 and it dosen't have this feature

Comment: +1 [here is the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3653.html).

Comment: the question is for c++11, where your suggestion doesn't work

Comment: I know it has been selected as the answer and all, but this isn't answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

This initialization:

```
s s1 = { 42 };
```

requires that `s` be an *aggregate*, or that it have a valid constructor taking e.g an int or an `std::initializer_list`.

When you add a member initialization at the point of declaration, you render your class `s` a non-aggregate, so you can no longer use aggregate initialization.

You could use the same initialization *syntax* for your non-aggregate by adding a constructor:

```
struct s
{
    s(int i) : i(i) {}
    int i=0;    
};
```

I believe this restriction has been relaxed for C++14.

See [What are aggregates...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) for more information.

Comment: It is not an explanation. The question is why aggregates may not have brace-or equal initializers for their members.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow because the standard says so. There isn't any explanation there, but I guess people realised that it was safe enough to do away with this rule for C++14.

Comment: I have come to this workaround too but it was precisely what I wanted to avoid

Comment: @CômeDavid I understand. I was not suggesting it as a work-around, just trying to show how a non-aggregate can be constructed with aggregate initialization syntax.